# Display list of checkbox items except selected dropdown item

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have dropdown list of items and a popup (used colorbox for opening popup) with a list of checkboxes. The popup is shown on click of *'+Add/Edit'*. Both the dropdown items and the checkboxes are generated in PHP from a `complaint.csv` file.

[image: The main form]
[image: The popup]

**complaint.csv file**

```
1,complaint type 1
2,complaint type 2
3,complaint type 3
etc...
```

**PHP code**

```
<label class="question-name" ng-class="{error:hasError()}">
  <span class="ng-binding" ng-hide="question.nameHiddenOnMobile">
    Chief Complaint
  </span>
  <span class="icon-required" ng-show="question.required"></span>
</label>

<select name="Language.PrimarySpoken" ng-hide="showAddAnswer"
        ng-model="question.response.value" 
        ng-options="a.text as a.getText() for a in question.answers.items"
        id="Language.PrimarySpoken" ng-value="a.text" class="input-wide" 
        ng-class="{error:hasError()}">
  <option class="hidden" disabled="disabled" value=""></option>

  <?php
    $file_handle = fopen("../complaint.csv", "r");
    while (!feof($file_handle)) {
      $lines_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);

    foreach ( $lines_of_text as $line_of_text): 
  ?>
      <option value="<?php print $line_of_text[1]; ?>">
        <?php print $line_of_text[1]; ?></option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <br/> <br/>

    <label class="question-name" ng-class="{error:hasError()}">
      <span class="ng-binding" ng-hide="question.nameHiddenOnMobile">
        Additional Complaint
      </span>
      <span class="icon-required" ng-show="question.required"></span>
    </label>

    <div class="form-row added ng-binding" ng-bind-html="question.getText()" id="text" ></div>
    <div class="form-row addlink ng-binding" 
         ng-bind-html="question.getText()">
      <em><a class='inline' href="#inline_content">+ Add/Edit</a></em>
    </div>

    <div style='display:none'>
      <div id='inline_content' style='padding:25px; background:#fff; font-size: 17px;'>

        <form action="" id="popup_form">

       <?php

        // Setup ---------------------------------------------------------------        
        define('numcols',4);  // set the number of columns here
        $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('../complaint.csv'));
        $numcsv = count($csv);
        $linespercol = floor($numcsv / numcols);
        $remainder   = ($numcsv % numcols);
        // Setup ---------------------------------------------------------------        


        // The n-column table --------------------------------------------------
        echo '<div class="table">'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '   <div class="column">'.PHP_EOL;

        $lines = 0;
        $lpc   = $linespercol;
        if ($remainder>0) { $lpc++; $remainder--; }
        foreach($csv as $item) {
            $lines++;
            if ($lines>$lpc) {
                echo '   </div>' . PHP_EOL . '<div class="column">'.PHP_EOL;
                $lines = 1;
                $lpc   = $linespercol;
                if ($remainder>0) { $lpc++; $remainder--; }
            }
            echo '      <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox'.$item[0].'" style="font-size:20px;">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="'.$item[1].'" id="checkbox'.$item[0].'" data-toggle="checkbox">'
                            .$item[1].
                        '</label><br />';
        }
        echo '   </div>'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '</div>'.PHP_EOL;
        // The n-column table --------------------------------------------------


    ?>
         <br/>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" id="update" 
                class="button button-orange" 
                style="width: 90px; margin-top: 450px; margin-left:-1062px;" 
                value="Update">
         <input type="submit" name="cancel" id="cancel" 
                class="button button-orange" 
                style="width: 90px; background-color:#36606e;" 
                value="Cancel">

        </form>    
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Question:**

1. If a *Main complaint* item is select then that same complaint does not appear in Additional Complaint list (i.e. if 'complaint type 1' is selected for Main complaint, 'complaint type 1' does not display on Additional Complaint list)

How should I get that using one `complaint.csv` file like checking for the selected item, and avoid it when displaying the list e.g  on select 'complaint type 1', the data from `complaint.csv` file will be display on popup checkbox list except 'complaint type 1' which is selected?

2. There is **empty space** generating if we remove the element. I don't want the empty space of removed item in checkbox list. Empty space means if 'complaint type 2' is removed then there empty space creates between 'complaint type 1' and 'complaint type 3'.

Is there any way to have `AJAX` for this situation like when the item is selected `AJAX` will call and it will remove the item from the checkbox list which is selected and then load the new items list except the selected one. (right now both list are loading at a same time on page load insted of that using `AJAX` the dropdown list should load on page load and checkbox list on click *'+Add/Edit'* button avoiding selected item.) Thus might be the empty space will not be there.

How this should be done using `AJAX`?

OR

Can anyone please suggest any solution with `PHP` or `JS` to get both requirements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. In your code, make sure the select dropdown value is `$line_of_text[0]` e.g. 1, 2, 3 etc.
2. Now add `onChange="hideSpaceAndComplain(this.value)"` on the select element.
3. Copy the following javascript function as is

   ```
   function hideSpaceAndComplain(id){

      //Hide selected one
      $("#popup_form").find('label').show(); 

      //Hide selected one
      $('input[value=' + id + ']').parents('label').hide();

      //Now rearrange all the visible label in columns 
      var visibleLabels = $("#popup_form").find('label:visible');

      visibleLabels.each(function(i,v){
         var column = Math.floor(i/4); // 4 being the number of column
         $(this).appendTo($("#popup_form").find('.column:eq('+column+')'));
      });
   }
   ```

This is doing both hiding the element which is selected and then re arranging the labels in column to remove one extra space.

Answer (score 4):

Since the logic you describe depends on what the user does *in the browser*, what you functionality does must be done in the browser, that means in Javascript.

According to the tags of the question you are using JQuery, so here are some pointers on how to do it with JQuery. First you have to attach an event handler to the dropdown to know when the user changes its value:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  //Put here what to do when the value of the dropdown changes.
}
```

In that function, you want to do two things:

- Un-hide the complaint that you may have hidden previously
- Hide the main complaint

To do so, write something like this in the event handler:

```
//Un-hide everything
$('label').show();

//Hide selected one
$('input[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').parent().hide();
```

You can see a working example in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uwk7w348/).
Hope this helps.

Note that I see in your code that you uses Angular, so you may want to use this instead. But I am not sure why you generate the `select` options *both* with Angular and PHP, so I am assuming this is some copy-pasted code that you are not using.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried your code but its not working in my case. I have to get the data from .csv file for both dropdown and checkbox list. is that the reason of not working?

Comment: One reason it may be not working in your case is because in the dropdown you assign the **first** column (`$line_of_text[0]`) to the value and the second column to the label, but in the checkboxes you assign the **second** column (`$item[1]`) to the value. I think both should have the first column as a value.

Comment: I changed the value of dropdown to `$line_of_text[1]` . But still not working. The checkbox list is on the popup. Does it reflecting the result?

Comment: I don't know... I can't execute and debug your code... To understand the problem you can use a tool such as Chrome developer tools or Firebug, and inspect the value of variables. You can also try to start from a working solution (my JS fiddle for example) and add your code little by little until in breaks, this will help you find the cause.

Comment: I have figure out the working code in  my case using yours. But the problem is I am getting empty space for the removed item. e.g. complaint type 2 removed then there is space between complaint type 1 and 3. complaint type 3 should take type 2's space like that. Is there any way to do that in JS?

Comment: As you wrap the complaints in `<div>` elements, maybe you have to hide the whole `div` element instead of the label element. For example: `$('input[value=' + $this.val() + ']').parents('div').first().hide();` instead of `$('input[value=' + $this.val() + ']').parent().hide();`. (To be adapted to your HTML)

Comment: Its hiding whole column from the list in which that selected item is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102459/discussion-between-kiran-and-djizeus).